# Laravel eloquent form: multiselect not persisting in edit

Tags: laravel, forms, eloquent, model

I have a eloquent model say `Math` which has a column in db say `number`, which is of type `array`

in db suppose,
for `id =1` `number = [1,2]`

When I try to `edit` this entry from `form`, I have to select values `1,2` again. As in the data is not persisting

```
if($form->isEditing()){
        $number = Math::where('id', 1)->pluck('number', 'number');
        $form->multipleSelect('number')->options(NumberList::all()->pluck('id', 'id'))->default($number);
}
```

I have tried doing the above, but the data is not persisting in edit mode. How to solve this?

Comment: Try dumping $numbers `dd($number);`